# Create a Websocket server hosted on Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a Lightning Aura Component that wants to setup bidirectional communication with another web platform.  Is there a way to create a Websocket server in Lightning and adjust its behavior to communicate to a platform outside of Salesforce?

Comment: I don't have a WebSocket server to experiment with, but according to the [Locker API Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer), the WebSocket object should function normally. Further research shows that CORS should not present any barriers to effectively using this technology. If you have a specific problem, please ask a specific question that includes code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox I actually have a working example from an aura component using `new Websocket(url)` that connects to a Websocket server (after whitelisting the http domain - using the ws server [here](https://flaviocopes.com/websockets/)).  I just haven't found an implementation of a Websocket server to host from Salesforce (like a public-facing site via a Visualforce page, leveraging a self-contained JS library for a Websocket. All the ones I've seen use Node.js or some other server side implementation)

Comment: You wouldn't be able to host a WS server in Salesforce, you'd need Heroku, Amazon EB/etc, or another type of server. Salesforce doesn't have any way to host custom services like this.